# How can I create two javascript arrays out of 1?

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
phrasePosNameSources = [
    {
        id: 0,
        longName: '#',
        name: '#'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        longName: 'Noun',
        name: 'N'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        longName: 'Verb',
        name: 'V'
    }

];
```

What I would like to do is to create two arrays based off this data that look like this:

```
phrasePosNames = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: '#'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'N'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'V'
    }

];

phrasePosLongNames = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: '#'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Noun'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Verb'
    }
];
```

Can someone give me some idea how I could do this with a modern browser?

Comment: You can loop over the array and construct 2 different arrays according to your requirements, did you face any difficulty on this approach ?

Comment: `var phrasePosNames = phrasePosNameSources.map(item => {id: item.id, name: item.name})` `var phrasePosLongNames = phrasePosNameSources.map(item => {id: item.id, name: item.longName})`

Comment: @vid - Can you add this as answer so I can accept. Thanks

Comment: @Samantha and Vid, 'map' is useful to manipulate an array by looping over all the elements, but using 'map' for this scenario needs to loop 2 times. We can achieve this using a single 'for' loop itself as shown in my answer, so I felt 'for' loop approach is better one, feel free to correct me if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this code block inline with my comment above, hope this helps, let me know if you need any clarity on this.

**Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s8e108cm/**

```
var phrasePosNameSources = [
    {
        id: 0,
        longName: '#',
        name: '#'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        longName: 'Noun',
        name: 'N'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        longName: 'Verb',
        name: 'V'
    }

];

var phrasePosNames = [];
var phrasePosLongNames = [];
for (var i=0; i < phrasePosNameSources.length; i++) {
phrasePosNames.push({
    id: phrasePosNameSources[i].id,
    name: phrasePosNameSources[i].name
});
phrasePosLongNames.push({
    id: phrasePosNameSources[i].id,
    name: phrasePosNameSources[i].longName
});
}
```